# Taking the contents of text file on parse and displaying in a textview in Swift

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

I am building a recipe directory and I seem to be stuck with this part. I have images, string, files in a class on parse. When the user selects an appetizer (table view controller), a new view controller will appear with the image, name and the recipe (textview) from the file (already placed on parse).

What am I doing wrong?

```
class MyAppetizerRecipes: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myTextView: UITextView!
    
    var recipes = [String: PFFile]()
    var appetizer = [String]()
    
    var images = [String: UIImage]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Appetizers")
        query.orderByAscending("recipe")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in
            
            guard error == nil, let objects = objects else {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            for object in objects {
                
                // *********** ... Appetizer Name ....... ************* //
            
            let appetizerName = object.objectForKey("appetizer") as! String
            self.name.text = self.valuePassed
            
            // *********** ... Recipe File on Parse ....... ************* //

            let recipeFile = object["recipe"] as! PFFile
            recipeFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (recipeData, error) -> Void in
                
                if error == nil {
                    
                    let data = recipeData
                    self.recipes[appetizerName] = PFFile(data: data!)

                 } else {
                    
                    print(error)
                    
                }
                
            })
            
            
            // *********** ... Image ....... ************* //
            
            let imageFile = object["imageFiles"] as!PFFile
            imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error)       -> Void in
                
                if error == nil {
                    
                    let data = imageData
                    
                } else {
                    
                    print(error)
                    
                }
                
                if let data = imageData {
                    
                    self.images[appetizerName] = UIImage(data: data)
                    self.imageView.image = self.images[self.valuePassed]
                    
                }
            })
            
        }

    }
    
}
```

[image: files on parse]

I am able to get an image and name of an appetizer, but not able to load text file from parse to UITextView.

Comment: "**I am able to get an image and name of an appetizer, but not the one i chose.**" dont understand what do u want to chose?

Comment: i was able to fix that issue., but i still can't load the .txt from parse to UITextView @FOOO

Comment: I updated my code in the post.

Comment: you are printing the error. What is the error? and where are you assigning myTextView.text in the code?

Comment: @FOOO the error prints nil if it occurs, but doesn't occur.  I am not assigning anything just yet to myTextView.text.  I have tried many things but when i try to assign the location as to the variable declared 'var recipes = [String: PFFile]()', it doesn't like that.  I know i am doing it wrong and need help as to how to do it.

Comment: @FOOO I also tried this but again wanted a string in contentsOfFile: 
var filePath = self.recipes[self.valuePassed]
let myText: String = NSString(contentsOfFile: recipe, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
self.myTextView.text = myText

Comment: When you call recipeFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (recipeData, error) what is the value of recipeData. use break point to check. First check whether data is coming.

Comment: @FOOO when i put 'print(recipeData)' after 'let data = recipeData', i get a bunch of numbers like '7420736f' <-- all different but too many to copy and paste here.